# Hide some elements in p:selectOneMenu primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a SelectOneMenu that I want hide somevalues that came from Bean based on condition (x.situacao eq 'INATIVO').

```
 <p:selectOneMenu id="selectonemenu" 
                    value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.profissao}" filter="true"
                    filterMatchMode="startsWith" converter="simpleEntityConverter"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Selecione uma Profissao para Pessoa">

                    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione..."
                        noSelectionOption="true" />

                    <f:selectItems value="#{profissaoBean.profissoes}" var="x"
                        itemLabel="#{x.nome}" itemValue="#{x}" 
                        itemDisabled="#{x.situacao eq 'INATIVO'}"/>

                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

As far I got is disabled value but not hide it from selectonemenu.

How do that? One way is filter this on Bean but I wanna use an already method that I have.

Comment: You could filter your collection of selectItems on server side and only pass the filtered collection to the client, or using CSS set { display: none } to disabled items should also work, I guess

Comment: @stg its so normal to have this behavior on elements like this that I wonder that JSF could have this implemented in some way.

Comment: I am currently using the first method (I am preparing those collections in my managedbean and do some ajax-updates, which works nice and does not break down the performance to much if the lists are not big (in my case ~100 to 200 items) ). Unfortunately the jsf-component selectItem/s does not support a build-in rendered-attribute. I have been looking for this as well a few month ago...

Comment: when using CSS, is this solution? .ui-selectlistbox-item.ui-state-disabled {
    display: none;
}